# Why is my jQuery code is unreachable in a blogger conditional statement?

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, blogger

Im coding in Blogger and trying to use jQuery to remove classes and then add some classes. The Conditional statement seems to work with some styles but not the script and seems unreachable since its not even logging in the console.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "https://testjvtdesigns.blogspot.com/"'>
        <style>
            .post {
                margin-bottom: 50px; 
                width: 100%
            }
        </style>
    <b:else/>
        <script type = "javascript">
            console.log('Im readable');
            $('.blog').removeClass('col-lg-9 col-md-9').addClass('col-lg-12 col-md-12');
        </script>
        <style>
            .side {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </b:if>
```

What i'm trying to do is the following. When a person goes into the site, the sidebar is present but when they go to the blog post, the sidebar is gone but I want the main to be full width. Which is why I want to remove the class and add another class. I guess I should mention the classes are bootstrap and the code is being place right above the closing head( ). The URL in the code is live, you can go and check it out if need be.

Comment: you could use the `data:blog.pageType` to check if it is index page or post page. https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your console: `$ is not defined`
Looks like you are attempting to run that script before jquery has loaded.

You could either call jquery earlier, load your script later or do something like the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     console.log('Im readable');
     $('.blog').removeClass('col-lg-9 col-md-9').addClass('col-lg-12 col-md-12');
});
```

I also noticed you have classes called `.blog` as well as `.Blog` - you should really be using different names or IDs for that.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much and thank you for your advice. I was thinking about changing it because of the similarities lol. :) BTW, I ended up loading jQuery earlier.

Comment: No worries - happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Does this fix the problem? I removed type = javascript (its optional in HTML5 and should be  **text/javascript**) and put the jQuery in a document.ready.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "https://testjvtdesigns.blogspot.com/"'>
        <style>
            .post {
                margin-bottom: 50px; 
                width: 100%
            }
        </style>
    <b:else/>
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            console.log('Im readable');
            $('.blog').removeClass('col-lg-9 col-md-9').addClass('col-lg-12 col-md-12');
});
        </script>
        <style>
            .side {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </b:if>
```

Comment: It seems to being reachable now but I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in the console.

Comment: did you import jquery?

Comment: @Jessica, Rich is correct you need to make you are embedding jQuery. I assumed you were embedding it in the template.

Comment: Yes, its on the bottom of the page.

Comment: Any calls to $ need to take place below the embedding of jQuery itself. If you try to access $ above the embedding of jQuery, your browser has no idea what is $.